# stage.scaleMode in external swf causes TypeError: Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3

When I try to load an external swf into the main file using this code

```
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Content.swf");
imageLoader.load(url);

imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
image.addChild(imageLoader);
}
```

and if the external swf has this code,

```
   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

then I get this error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. But if the swf has TLF text in it (or at least just a TLF text field without even a character) then everything is alright. With classic text the error still exists.  Why does presence of TLF text in the external swf fix the problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` in your external swf to be sure that stage is accessable:

```
public function astest1()
{
    if(stage)
        init();
    else
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

protected function init(event:Event = null):void
{
    if(event)
        EventDispatcher(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);

    trace("stage = ", stage);
}
```

As for TLF has fixed the issue I guess it may be RSL influence, it's most likely that flash loads tlf runtime library so it delay the calling of the costructor of your swf, so the main swf adds the loader with external swf (and make `stage` accessable to the external swf) by this, but it's unstable sure ) In both cases I recommend you listen `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event before the stage using.